# Warning message with close action on top of Browser Frame

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

We have divided the web view into three main windows. On the top window we have action buttons and on the left navigation

In the other window (bigger than 2),, I am using Kibana dashboard to get displayed using BrowserFrame

What I am trying to do is,

I want to display a warning message on the dashboard using layout but unfortunately, I was not success giving

```
VerticalLayout vertical = new VerticalLayout();
      Label warningLabel = new Label("Warning : Dashboard is only accessible under company network/VPN.");
      BrowserFrame boxInfo = new BrowserFrame(null, new ExternalResource(address));
      boxInfo.setSizeFull();
      vertical.addComponent(warningLabel);
      vertical.addComponent(boxInfo);
      vertical.setSpacing(false);
      vertical.setSizeFull();
      body.addComponent(vertical);
```

When I use vertical layout, the two components are separated by huge white space. Please suggest me which layout could be used.

The user should close the label by clicking on the "X" of the label like below

Warning : Dashboard is only accessible under company network/VPN.        X

Please let me know how to do this as well. Your pointers will help me a lot

Comment: The VerticalLayout distributes the available space equally between you 3 rows. You can modfy this with: `vLayout.setExpandRation()`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now there is no spacing but the browser frame is displayed as small size with scroll bar at the right. can you tell me how to increase the height ?

Comment: You have to keep the setSizeFull on the boxInfo and set its expand ratio to 1. The label needs to have an expand ratio of 0. This will expand the boxInfo and squeeze the label

Comment: E.g. add this after adding the boxInfo:     vertical.setExpandRatio(boxInfo, 1);